# How apply additional conditions for ActiveRecord joins

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

Suppose I try to calculate a count of accidents for each division for some period of time. So I have 2 tables. I am trying to use ActiveRecord to get my answer and it looks like this

```
class Division < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :accidents

end

class Accident < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :division

end


Division.left_joins(:accidents).where('accidents.occurred_at > ?', Time.now - 1.year).group(:name).count
```

In this case ActiveRecord generate this SQL

```
SELECT COUNT(accidents.id) AS "count_all", "divisions"."name" AS "divisions_name"
FROM "divisions"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "accidents" ON "accidents"."division_id" = "divisions"."id"
WHERE (accidents.occurred_at > '2022-07-30 20:56:10.178153')
GROUP BY "divisions"."name"
```

Problem here is that if accidents count for some division is 0 we will not see it in query result, so I need SQL to be like this

```
SELECT COUNT(accidents.id) AS "count_all", "divisions"."name" AS "divisions_name"
FROM "divisions"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "accidents" ON "accidents"."division_id" = "divisions"."id" and accidents.occurred_at > '2022-07-30 20:56:10.178153'
GROUP BY "divisions"."name"
```

Is it possible to specify some additional conditions for join?
I know that we can specify additional conditions for has_many relation, but it will be a static conditions. I want it to be dynamic depending on user request parameters

I am trying to avoid using raw sql for join condition e.q.

```
Division.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN accidents ON accidents.division_id = divisions.id
and (accidents.occurred_at > '2022-07-30 20:56:10.178153'").group(:name).count('accidents.id')
```

Comment: the additional conditions should be a `where` clause, not part of the `joins` clause

Comment: Not sure whether what you're asking for will give you what you're after. The `LEFT JOIN` with the `occurred_at` logic will only mean that the fields for the right table (`accidents`) will be `null`, so the group/count output will be the same whether that condition is present or not.

Comment: @smathy I corrected question, yes I need COUNT(accidents.id). So this query should return 0 for those division who don't have accidents

Comment: @LesNightingill if i will use where clause, I will not get division that have no accidents. And I will need do collect them separately

Comment: _I am trying to avoid using raw sql for join condition_ — I think it's ok to use such raw SQL for JOIN. Alternatively you can use Arel

Comment: @DavidAsatryan counting the NULLs in `accidents.id` will still result in the same row count. Good luck though, this was just an aside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's about using scope with `JOIN` to simplify final query?

```rb
class Division < ApplicationRecord
  scope :with_accidents_from, ->(occurred_at) do
    joins_query =
      sanitize_sql([
        'LEFT OUTER JOIN accidents ON accidents.division_id = divisions.id AND accidents.occurred_at > ?',
        occurred_at
      ])

    joins(joins_query)
  end
end
```

And then

```rb
Division.with_accidents_from(1.year.ago).group(:name).count('accidents.id')
```

Comment: Wow, interesting, looks like what I want, thank you, will try this approach

Answer (score 1):

I would try an [association with a scope](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#scopes-for-has-many) like this

```
# in the model
class Division < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :accidents
  has_many :recent_accidents, class_name:  'Accident', 
                              foreign_key: 'division_id',
                              -> { where occurred_at: (1.year.ago..) }
```

and would use it like this:

```
Division.left_outer_joins(:recent_accidents)
        .group(:name)
        .count('accidents.id')
```

Comment: Thanks, but what if I want dynamic parameter for occurred_at, depending on user parameter?

Comment: Then you will need to use the `outer_left_joins` with the longer string.